# How to get slow response services in bulk email using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want email notification after completion of test i have more than 100 samplers so i need bulk mail which should contain only slow response services/samplers  how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following setup:

1. Amend JMeter configuration to save only failed samples and to store the results as soon as they appear by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=false
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```

   JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up
2. Use [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) with some form of threshold to mark "slow" samplers with response times lower than that threshold as failed
3. Use [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) and [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) to send the results where required.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter)